# Shopify Multipass in Dev Shop

Tags: node.js, shopify, multipass

I'm attempting to test out Multipass in a dev shop, I managed to get the Multipass logic implemented in Node.js

Now I'm getting the error: "You are not authorized to use Multipass login"

I have Multipass enabled in settings, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Hey! Have you been able to find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that this feature is traditionally enabled for only for “Plus” accounts

Comment: I actually have a Plus account. However, I'm getting the same error you got. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Generally this error means you are sending the "remote_ip" parameter but the IP address of the browser making the request doesn't match the one in the parameter.